# Removing "ser" from series in biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieee-style

I would like to remove the "ser." from series when using `biblatex` with biber backend. A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,giveninits=true,maxcitenames=99]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pubs.bib}
@incollection{key, 
  year = {2014},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  volume = {8451},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  editor = {Editor Middle Name},
  doi = {1234},
  title = {Title of article},
  publisher = {Big Book Publisher},
  author = {First Author and Second Author},
  pages = {1--150},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{./pubs.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{key}

\end{document}
```

This appears as

[image]

Comment: If the 'ser' is incorrect here according to IEEE rules, you might want to give the developer a shout: https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{series}
 {#1}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but not sure why that should be a non-breaking space: no reason to avoid a break at that point.

Comment: Oh! yes. You're right – without `ser.`, it becomes meaningless.  Thank you for pointing it. It's fixed.

Comment: I think we don't need any `\addspace` whatsoever, `{#1}` alone is enough. And I have to say I really dislike your alternative variant. Suppressing fields or strings by setting them to empty could cause problems for the punctuation tracker (not sure if `\bibstring` guards against that, but `\DeclareFieldFormat` has problems with that at times)

Comment: @moewe: Didn't know these problems with the punctuation tracker. I just tested it worked.  I've removed the variant. Thanks for the iformation.

Comment: As I said. I'm not sure if `\bibstring` guards against empty strings. And problems with empty `\DeclareFieldFormat`s don't surface that often either, but I wouldn't want to risk it.